# Why does ssh not work all the time?

Tags: mobaxterm

I have two commands below that work when I use the command prompt but not in mobaxterm. Why?

```
ssh -L 16006:127.0.0.1:6006 xyz@10.2.1.243
```

works in command prompt and mobaxterm but

```
ssh -L 16006:127.0.0.1:6006 xyz@10.2.25
```

does not work only in mobaxterm. It gives me the message

> _ssh: Could not resolve hostname 10.2.25: Name or service not known

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's not the same `ssh`.**

In Bash inside MobaXterm `ssh` is aliased to `/bin/ssh.exe` which is a shell script which eventually runs `/bin/_ssh.exe`. These files were installed with MobaXterm. Outside MobaXterm they exist in `%MyDocuments%\MobaXterm\slash\bin`.

Your command prompt uses *some other* `ssh.exe`.

An IP address with only two dots [is valid](https://superuser.com/a/486904/432690), still in practice some tools may disagree. And it's not the only possible cause to disagree, see [this question about leading zeros](https://superuser.com/q/857603/432690).

---

To make both methods behave in the same way, you need to use *the same* `ssh.exe` each time.

- Always use `ssh` from MobaXterm.

  Note even if you add `%MyDocuments%\MobaXterm\slash\bin` to your `PATH` in Windows, you won't be able to use `ssh.exe` from MobaXterm because it's not an executable Windows would understand. You can use `_ssh.exe` though: copy it to another location, rename to `ssh.exe` adjust `PATH` in Windows. This `ssh` will *not* support addresses like `xyz@10.2.25`.
- Or the other way around: always use the other `ssh`.

  - The simplest approach seems to redefine the `ssh` alias in Bash inside MobaXterm to point to `ssh.exe` used by your command prompt.

    ```
    alias ssh='/cygdrive/c/proper/path/ssh.exe'
    ```

    But note the original `/bin/ssh.exe` *script* is there for a reason. So maybe it's better to leave the original alias intact and to…
  - patch `SSH_PROG="/bin/_ssh.exe"` in the script and point to `/cygdrive/c/proper/path/ssh.exe`. The "new" `ssh.exe` may not be fully compatible with the script though. Future updates (if any) may revert the changes.

  Anyway in your case this `ssh` should support addresses like `xyz@10.2.25`.

Even if you use the same `ssh.exe` but still rely on the script in one case, the results may not be strictly identical because the script does something extra.

Answer (score -1):

10.2.25 is an incomplete IP address, you're missing digits there.  That's why the "hostname" doesn't get resolved

Comment: but i can ssh through command prompt no problem

Comment: only with the first command line, whjich is complete. The second one you listed has the target IP incomplete, hence the error with the hostname which can't be resolved

Comment: no i can ssh with both if using the command prompt.